# void* D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE::pData to OLE_COLOR* possible?

Tags: c++, directx11

I have found the following from this link
[enter link description here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ns-d3d11-d3d11_mapped_subresource)

> pData
>
> Type: void*
>
> Pointer to the data. When ID3D11DeviceContext::Map provides the
>   pointer, the runtime ensures that the pointer has a specific
>   alignment, depending on the following feature levels:
>
> For D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0 and higher, the pointer is aligned to 16
>   bytes. For lower than D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0, the pointer is aligned
>   to 4 bytes.

Would someone please explain if I can reinterpret cast the void pointer into OLE_COLOR* or not?

Comment: What's OLD_HANDLE ?

Comment: Sorry it should be OLE_COLOR*. I edited.

Comment: That should be fine. You need to take care of memory alignment. This should be fine for pointers allocated via 'new' or other memory allocators, but be careful passing subscripts (e.g.  the 2nd element of an array, that may not be aligned to 16 bytes like the [0]th element)